# Can I use a display driver from Windows 8 in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, windows-8-preview

My latest display driver doesn't support WDDM 1.0, and I need it to be at least version 1.1.

I've been attempting to get the Windows Phone 7 SDK working on my HP Pavillion dv9000, but the phone emulator requires 1.1 or higher. My drivers are as up-to-date as they can get. I even tried a modded driver found [here](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/27593-v26309-windows-7vista-32bit-nvidia-desktop/page__p__134247), but no go.

Then, while evaluating Windows 8 Developer Preview on a different partition I noticed that dxdiag.exe showed it was using WDDM 1.2. I tried installing Windows Phone 7 SDK on Windows 8, but I get an "Internal Error" popup and "Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments" in the error window in Visual Studio. I'm guessing because Windows Phone 7 SDK isn't supported on Windows 8 yet.

So my question is this: **Can I get Windows 7 to use the display driver Windows 8 is using to get WDDM 1.2 on Windows 7 and how would I go about doing it?**

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 uses Hyper-V technology for virtualization, which is not compatible with the current Windows Phone development tools. There are a couple of possible options if you really *have* to work in a virtual machine on Windows 8:

1. Uninstall Hyper-V from Windows 8.
2. Create a 32-bit Windows 8 Hyper-V image on Windows 8.

If you're only evaluating Windows 8, then option 1 is likely to be the better option. If you need Hyper-V, then option 2 will work, but it's going to be quite slow (as is any kind of development inside the virtual machine).

For more information/detail, take a look at this blog post: http://wp.me/p1OzDh-5w

Comment: Are you assuming I'm running Windows 8 in a virtual machine on Windows 7 or that I installed Windows 7 using this "Hyper-V" inside Windows 8? I'm running no virtual machine. The two OS's are on separate partitions of my hard drive.

Comment: Also, Hyper-V is not checked in the Windows Features window, so it looks like it's already uninstalled.

Comment: It's grayed out, not because it is already uninstalled, but rather because your hardware isn't compatible.  Hyper-V install is an option, even after the OS has been installed.

Comment: I didn't say it was grayed out. It's unchecked.